# Escaping SED command

Tags: php, linux, sed, escaping

I am trying to run a script to replace a section of code in a lot of .php files. I need to replace:

```
`popupOpen(\'/home/open.php?c='.urlencode($row['id']).'&s=\', 650, 600)`
```

with this:

```
`popupOpen(\'/home/open.php?c='.urlencode($row['id']).'&s=\', 1024, 750)`
```

The command I am using is:

```
find . -name "index.php" -print | xargs sed -i "s/popupOpen(\\\'\/home\/open.php?c='.urlencode\($row\['id']\).'\&s=\\\', 650, 600)/popupOpen(\\\'\/home\/open.php?c='.urlencode\($row\['id']\).'\&s=\\\', 1024, 750)/g"
```

I just cant seem to escape it properly. What am I missing?

Comment: Your saying alot of file, but you are just looking for `index.php`

Comment: Where I will run the command has about 120 folders each with index.php.

Comment: it looks to me you only need to replace 650 with 1024 and 600 with 750

Comment: I could shorten the command to make it simpler, but I would like to know what exactly needs escaped in case I have to run similar commands in the future that may be more complicated.

Comment: Sean: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html - And if it helps, try in the shell first, then try to assign the command to a string variable in PHP. Then output the string variable and verify it *is* the command that worked in shell.

Comment: you also need to escape the `$`, ohterwise `$row` will be expanded by the shell (probably to the empty string)... maybe you should consider putting the sed script into a file and call that with `sed -f script`. makes escaping a little easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can do without `xargs`:

```
find .name "index.php" -exec sed -i '' sed "whatever" {} \;
```

and in this case I think this will work:

```
find . -name "index.php" -exec sed "s|popupOpen(\\\\'/home/open\.php\?c=\'\.urlencode(\\\$row\[\'id\'\])\.\'&s=\\\\', 650, 600)|popupOpen(\\\\'/home/open\.php\?c=\'\.urlencode(\\\$row\[\'id\'\])\.\'\&s=\\\\', 1024, 750)|g" {} \;
```